# Upgrading dual-boot (Ubuntu Studio 20.04 / Windows 10) to Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, upgrade, windows, 22.04

I realize this is an Ubuntu forum (as opposed to an Ubuntu Studio forum), so apologies if I'm posting in the wrong place. If this is the case, could you kindly point me to the correct place to ask this question?

I'm currently running a dual boot system with Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and Windows 10 on a Lenovo desktop.  The system came with Windows 10 installed and I added Ubuntu Studio 20.04 later.  Everything has been running well for the past 2 years.  Now I want to upgrade the Ubuntu Studio side to 22.04, but I want to make sure I'm not risking the Windows side.  I've looked for articles / videos on this topic, but I only find information about creating the dual-boot (i.e., a new install of Ubuntu along side existing Windows).  I'm looking for information on any special steps I need to follow in order to UPGRADE the Ubuntu side without disturbing Windows.  In particular, is there anything special I need to worry about with the boot loader (grub?) or the disk partitioning?

Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Ubuntu Studio is a fully-supported flavor of Ubuntu. The question is welcome here.

Comment: I can only give opinion, but I'm involved in QA testing of Ubuntu *flavors* & main Ubuntu Desktop. Upgrade your system normally (using [ubuntu-release-upgrader tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) and dual boot won't be impacted, you can also re-install Ubuntu (& *flavors* like Ubuntu Studio) without impacting the dual boot.  Ubuntu won't impact partitioning (*except if you change it during a re-install but you can re-install without changes there too*) & only updates grub *in-place*. I'd not expect any issues if fastboot & windows hibernate is off/disabled.

Comment: FYI:  This site is a Ubuntu (& official flavor) Q&A site where Ubuntu Studio is a [*flavor*](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) thus welcome. Ubuntu Forums is found here https://ubuntuforums.org/ where your question would also be welcome

Answer (score 1):

An ordinary *release-upgrade* of any Ubuntu flavor will NOT re-partition your storage devices or threaten any other OS (like Windows). It's not a reinstall.

But that doesn't mean it is completely safe. Release Upgrades work properly for most folks. But a few do run into problems, sometimes serious.

A release-upgrade is also the time that your system is most vulnerable to damage from many kinds of folly -- including folly that occurred in the past and wasn't fully cleaned up. The surest way to prevent an unexpected catastrophe is to be prepared for it.

- Backing up ALL your data on both OS before starting is very wise. Knowing how to restore from those backups is important, too.
- Have new install USBs for both OS handy.
- Uninstall all non-Ubuntu applications and software before starting. That means trying to return your Ubuntu Studio system to as close to stock condition as possible. (It does NOT mean uninstalling Windows).
- If you have a highly-customized system, uptime-essential, or other high-value consider cloning it. Make all your mistakes on the clone.
- Read all output carefully.
- Schedule a whole afternoon for your first release-upgrade. Don't try to hurry it (you can't).

A few minutes to patiently prepare backups and install USBs and to be generally organized before major surgery (even if it's routine) can save you days of frustration and rebuilding, and possibly years of regret over unnecessarily lost data.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did (almost) the same thing.  Dual-booting Win10 and Lubuntu 20.04 LTS, then upgraded to Win10 and Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS.

Since I was changing a lot all at once, I just did a clean install, not an upgrade.  You may or may not want to do it that way.  Ran the live USB, did a custom install, and told it to use the partition that still had the old Lubuntu on it.

That's pretty much all there was to it.  Windows didn't change at all, the new GRUB found it, and the new Ubuntu Studio simply replaced the old Lubuntu.  Then I spent some good quality time exploring the new system and setting things up again, most of which couldn't be copied directly because of the different resource managers between different flavors.  If you had customized GRUB before, you'll probably need to do that again too, as I did.

I would advise, though, to wait a bit longer if you can.  At least until the second point release comes out.  (22.04.2)  I was somewhat forced to be an earlier adopter than I really wanted, because Lubuntu decided to ignore my integrated graphics which in turn shut off the laptop screen.  I stuck out long enough to get the first point release, but it still has bugs.  Subsequent updates have fixed several of them (`sudo apt {update|full-upgrade|autoremove}`), but there are still some important ones left as I see it.

---

I pulled my removable hard drive during the upgrade, just to make sure that I didn't end up accidentally depending on it to boot.  I made that mistake years ago, not again since.

And it's a good idea to back up everything important before you do anything.  I usually just image the entire drive (including Windows) to some external storage, by fully booting into the live CD or USB (not the quick-install or whatever it calls that) and using `dd` from there before installing.  Then unmount and unplug the external storage before running the installer.  If it all goes sideways, then you can boot into the live image again and `dd` back the other way.

Comment: According to the Ubuntu Studio 22.04 website upgrades from versions prior to 21.10 are not supported.  It also points out that 21.10 has reached end-of-life (?) and upgrades from that version may have been turned off.  The site offers some suggestions but warns they "may or may not work".  So now I'm looking for a predictably reliable way to upgrade my Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS release (which should still be supported) to 22.04 LTS.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @TimL Yeah, that's kind of a sticky situation.  I had that thought immediately when I read that myself.  But the fact remains that you're pretty much changing everything anyway, and that's a major operation with lots of opportunity for things to go wrong.  So the common advice applies as always, to back up everything in case it goes south, do nothing else until you have that backup, and then just do it.

Comment: @TimL There's also some benefit to fresh-installing once in a while, instead of a series of upgrades.  So you manually carry over what you actually want to keep, and discover what the new system can actually do, instead of inheriting more and more of a mess of automated adaptations that don't necessarily know how to handle your specific situation, and your own hacks that might have officially-supported solutions now.  Still back up the old one, of course, but a big part of that backup is documenting what you do with it and how to set that up manually in case it isn't built-in yet.

Comment: @TimL In the case of this particular upgrade, there are so many fundamental differences that they just gave up on the automated translation.  I like what they've gone to, but I'd still call it immature at this moment.  For example: https://askubuntu.com/q/1432146/321777

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll first try a live boot from a thumb drive to see if things are working.  If so, I'll backup everything and do a full install (with fingers crossed).  Thanks again!